# Android Studio не видит изменений

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Выдавало ошибку, что нет таблицы в бд. Я заменил бд и имя таблицы, но ошибка (no such table: ... ) заявляет что нет имени старой таблицы, хотя я ее нигде и не вызываю. А потом заметил что изменения не вносятся в принципе. У меня был вывод  `LOG.d(... , ...);`
Так вот я его удалил, а он все равно выводится... А новые НЕ выводятся.  Перезапуск не помог. Студия последняя.

Как решить? Может это норма, я полный ноль пока в этом.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема может быть в двух местах.

1. Вы изменили таблицу в коде, но на девайсе осталась старая. Решается это изменением версии БД при обращении к ней. В этом случае будет вызван метод `onUpgrade` где вы сможете пересоздать таблицы.
2. У вас вторая студия и не отключён `InstantRun`. В этом случае некоторые изменения в коде могут не отображаться пока вы не отключите эту функцию в настройках IDE

Comment: Да, оно, спасибо!